# Kubernetes: minikube persistent volume local filesystem storage location

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I've read through all the docs and a few SO posts and can't find an answer to this question:

Where does minikube persist its persistent volumes in my local mac filing system?

Thanks

Comment: Which type of volume are you using? hostPath or other?

Comment: Besides other questions, are you using Windows or Linux machine? Or maybe you have Minikube on some virtualization app like VMWare or VirtualBox?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all keep in mind that Kubernetes is running on [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/) cluster. `Minikube` itself run on Virtual Machine, so all data would be stored in this VM not on your MacOS.

When you want to point exact place where you would like to save this data in Kubernetes you could choose between:

- [hostpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath)

> A hostPath volume mounts a file or directory from the host node's filesystem into your Pod. This is not something that most Pods will need, but it offers a powerful escape hatch for some applications.

- [local](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local)

> A local volume represents a mounted local storage device such as a disk, partition or directory.
>
> Local volumes can only be used as a statically created PersistentVolume. Dynamic provisioning is not supported yet.
>
> Compared to hostPath volumes, local volumes can be used in a durable and portable manner without manually scheduling Pods to nodes, as the system is aware of the volume's node constraints by looking at the node affinity on the PersistentVolume.

However, `Minikube` **supports only** `hostpath`.

In this case you should check `Minikube documentation` about [Persistent Volumes](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/)

> minikube supports `PersistentVolumes` of type `hostPath` out of the box. These PersistentVolumes are mapped to a directory inside the running minikube instance (usually a VM, unless you use `--driver=none`, `--driver=docker`, or `--driver=podman`). For more information on how this works, read the Dynamic Provisioning section below.
>
> minikube is configured to persist files stored under the following
> directories, which are made in the Minikube VM (or on your localhost
> if running on bare metal). You may lose data from other directories on
> reboots.
>
> - /data
> - /var/lib/minikube
> - /var/lib/docker
> - /tmp/hostpath_pv
> - /tmp/hostpath-provisioner

If you would like to mount directory from host you would need to use `minikube mount`.

```
$ minikube mount <source directory>:<target directory>
```

For more details, please check [Minikube Mounting filesystems](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/) documentation.

Comment: Isn't one of the benefits of Minikube the fact that it *should* mount local dirs directly on the VM? It always worked like this, silently; but now I have a Minikube 1.21 that didn't mount `/Users` from macOS (`minikube ssh -- ls -la /Users`), and had to fix manually with `minikube mount` as you showed. And in case you wonder, no, I never used the `--disable-driver-mounts` flag. ‍♂️

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the volume type `hostPath` the files are saved on your node.

To access your node filesystem you can use the command: `minikube ssh` and under your mounted path you'll find your documents.

Comment: That just ssh's into the virtual machine .. im trying to find the location of the files on my actual file system, or how to mount them. When i try and use virtual box and mount a local directory to use with a pv i get a permissions error. Even if i ssh in, how do i copy the files and get them outside

Comment: You have to define your volume in your .yaml configuration and then you'll find your files under that path

Comment: @HappyMachine see PjoterS' answer: Minikube is supposed to mount automatically your host filesystem (verify with `minikube ssh -- ls -la /Users`). If it doesn't, then *"there's some weird problem with Minikube"* ™ (what a surprise.. ); however you can manually mount via `minikube mount /Users:/Users` and your deployment mount will not fail anymore.

Answer (score 1):

When you create PV and PVC configuration yaml file, you can mention same **storageClassName** in both yaml files.

This way the Persistent Volume Claim gets bind to that respective Persistent Volume and uses the hostpath to store the data.

You can run `kubectl describe pv <pv-name>` and `kubectl describe pvc <pvc-name>` and see the storageClassName matches. Also in the output of the describe pv you can notice the host path directory details.